# Can windows use the verb “lead”?

Tags: word-choice

Can I use *lead to* in my sentence?

"Which side do the windows of our new house lead to?"

Comment: Only use "lead to" if you're using them to get in and out of the house. Otherwise, you'd probably say which way they *face*.

Comment: To add to what Old Brixtonian said, this sounds like there's windows on only one side of the new house. That's a strange kind of house. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, they are on all sides. Is it wrong to use "side"?

Comment: And can I thus say "They lead to the north" and "They face the north"?

Comment: No, you can't say they "lead to the north", because windows by themselves, don't lead anywhere. They face a direction.

Comment: Is "They face the north" correct? And is "side" correct in "which side do they face"?

Comment: They don't *face* a side of the house, they're just *on* a side of the house.  Like "This window is on the north side of the house" or "this window faces north".

Comment: As @stangdon said, it's "this window faces north". North is not a specific, unique thing -- it's a general direction, and because a window doesn't lead anywhere, you don't need *the*. Compare this to a trail, or a road -- "the road leads north". You follow a road; you can't follow a window.

Comment: If none of these answers is satisfying to you, it's because we don't have enough context. Where did you see or where are you intending to use this sentence?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It's my own sentence, gotube. I noticed that some of you capitalized "north". Is capitalization optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "lead" in the sense used in the question, indicates a direction that can be **followed* It is often used when giving directions, or describing a route that one can take.

> - All roads lead to Rome.
> - The hall heads to the kitchen
> - Route 86a leads to Germantown.
> - The back door leads to the ally.

It is much more naturally used of a door than of a window, unless the window is being used or considered as a route of passage, as in:

> The window leads only to a 50-story drop.

To describe the position of a window in a house or other building, one can use "faces", "looks out on" or "is in the X side". For example:

> - The window faces North
> - The window faces the street.
> - The upper window looks out on the side lawn.
> - The now window is in the West side of the house.